# Trying to add all borders to range with variable row count in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, border

I am trying to add all borders to the contents below the headers that I have. The range would be A7 to Ox where x is the last row of content.  The first part of the code listed looks for CFS-GHOST-DJKT and deletes the row which works perfectly.  I am unsure about how to select the lower ending row correctly.

```
Dim x As Long
For x = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 7 Step -1
    If Cells(x, "A") = "CFS-GHOST-DJKT" Then Rows(x).Delete


'Add Gridlines=========================================================


      Range(A7, Ox).Select
      With Selection.Borders
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlThin

      End With
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a term of `Range(A7, Ox)` is telling VBA to select the rectangular area defined by the `Address` of the variable (of type `Range`) `A7` as one corner and the `Address` of the variable (also of type `Range`) `Ox` as the other corner.

As you have defined neither of those variables, your code fails.

Try this instead:

```
Dim x As Long
For x = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row To 7 Step -1
    If Cells(x, "A") = "CFS-GHOST-DJKT" Then Rows(x).Delete
Next

With Range("A7:O" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Borders
    .LineStyle = xlContinuous
    .ColorIndex = 0
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .Weight = xlThin
End With
```